# Assign value to multidimentional array in smarty

Tags: multidimensional-array, smarty

I would like to assign a value to multidimentional array with Smarty.

To assign value to a variable, I use below code.

```
{assign='data1', value='this is data'}
```

I have a variable, `$cart[products]` and would like to assign a value to that variable.

I have tried using `{assign='cart.products', value='this is data'}` but the data doesn't enter the variable.

Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the value into an array.

```
{assign var=carts value=['products'=>'this is data']}
```

It is explained well in http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.variables.tpl.